# WebView in React-Native is not showing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to add a WebView in my project, in React-Native. The problem is that writing it so:

```
import {WebView} from "react-native-webview";
```

```
<View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
      <WebView source={{ uri: 'https://google.com'}}  />
</View>
```

it is showing nothing. If in WebView's style I set heigth and width to something it works, but I want to see it full-screen. How can i do it?

Comment: <View style={{flex:10}}>
<WebView style={{flex:1}} />
</View>
<View style={{flex:1}}>
<WebView style={{flex:1}} />
</View>

Comment: Excuse me, what is this meaning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

Method - 1:

```
 <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
          <WebView style = {{flex:1}} source={{ uri: 'https://google.com'}}  />
    </View>
```

Method - 2 :

```
 <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
          <WebView style = {{width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
height: Dimensions.get('window').height}} source={{ uri: 'https://google.com'}}  />
    </View>
```

Comment: The flexDirection in the wrapper view component seemed to do the trick for me

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { WebView, View } from 'react-native';


export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row' }}>
        <WebView source={{ uri: 'https://google.com' }} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Expo snack:
https://snack.expo.io/@djalik/5a98e2

Comment: Can you explain the problem? more details?

Comment: Well, it uses WebView imported from 'react-native', but I cannot, because it reports me that it was removed, and I have to use 'react-native-webview'

Comment: Do you speak about this issue: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview/issues/491

Comment: Did you use last version of react-native-webview: v7.0.5